# Как с помощью stream API найти у одного атрибута коллекции количество упоминаний другого атрибута?

Tags: java, xml, java-stream

Из локального файла xml считываю данные и хочу по этим данным пройтись для поиска информации.

Кусок данных из xml:

```
<item city="Апатиты" street="Дорожная улица" house="171" floor="5" />
<item city="Владивосток" street="Кооперативная улица" house="192" floor="2" />
<item city="Арсеньев" street="1-я Майская улица" house="104" floor="4" />
<item city="Бийск" street="Дзержинского, улица" house="23" floor="2" />
<item city="Ангарск" street="Зелёная улица" house="91" floor="4" />
<item city="Апатиты" street="Красноармейская улица" house="123" floor="2" />
<item city="Владивосток" street="Ноградская улица" house="142" floor="5" />
<item city="Арсеньев" street="Волосницына улица" house="165" floor="2" />
<item city="Бийск" street="Ленина улица" house="22" floor="3" />
<item city="Ангарск" street="Первая улица" house="11" floor="4" />
```

Как с помощью stream API вывести список городов и количество 1,2,3,4,5 этажных зданий в этих городах?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для данной задачи нужно построить вложенную хэш-таблицу `Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer>>`, группируя входные данные при помощи `Collectors::groupingBy`:

1. по названиям городов (внешний  уровень)
2. по количеству этажей: ключ - этажность дома, значение -- количество домов

Также следует предварительно отфильтровать входной поток адресов по этажности.

Для получения отсортированных таблиц по ключу следует использовать вариант
с `Supplier<Map>`: `TreeMap::new`.

```java
List<Address> addresses = ...; // исходный список адресов из XML
Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer>> floorStatsPerCity = addresses
    .stream()
    .filter(addr -> addr.getFloor() <= 5) // дома с этажностью [1..5]
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Address::getCity, // ключ - название города
        TreeMap::new, // отсортировать таблицу по названию города
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            Address::getFloor, TreeMap::new, Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)
        )
    ));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! 
Еще небольшой вопрос вдогонку: у меня поле floor в entity-классе Address имеет тип String и я хочу использовать equals() вместо <=
Как мне в equals() передать диапазон (1-5) значений floor. Есть мысль через if() сделать equals каждого значения(1,2,3,4,5), но не знаю - может ли это реализовываться в streamAPI. 
Может поможет переопределение метода equals()?

Comment: Тогда просто изменится тип ключа во вложенной таблице -- станет `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>`.  Фильтрацию по количеству этажей можно сделать разнами способами ('equals' не подходит): преобразовав `floor` в число:  `.filter(addr -> Integer.parseInt(addr.getFloor()) <= 5)`, или использовав `String::matches`: `.filter(addr -> addr.getFloor().matches("[1-5]"))` (любая одна цифра от 1 до 5)